# what's the meaning of We're just finishing dinner?

Tags: tense

1. We have just finished dinner.
2. We will finish dinner very soon

Comment: The title **We're just finishing**...  is different from the two examples mentioned in the body.

Comment: @ @Mari-Lou A Hi.I edited that question. The edition of that question is not visible to you yet.

Comment: @MariosAthanasiou Maybe YQ CUI ***wants*** to know the difference between"*will finish*", "*just finishing*" and "*just finished*" We don't know, so I would leave it for the OP to clarify.

Comment: @MariosAthanasiou In the suggested edit, you wrote: *"Our English teacher wrote on the blackboard the following sentences"* But how do you know where YQ CUI saw those sentences? Please don't add any extra information without knowing for sure

Comment: _We are just finishing dinner_ means that we are at the last stage of the meal and will very soon have finished.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A OK. First, I will wait the OP to clarify the question.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. Q 1 and 2 are the OP's interpretations. BUT YQ CUI, you must make this clearer, one user was going to remove the sentence in the title all together.

Comment: @YQ CUI Hi. Do you want to know the difference in meaning between the sentences 'We're just finishing dinner', 'We have just finished dinner' and 'We will finish dinner very soon'?

Answer (score 2):

“We’re just finishing dinner” means that at this very moment (right now) we are eating dinner and have very nearly finished doing so. So there’s probably only very little food left on our plates, and—unless we are going to linger in conversation—we will soon get up from the table.

Answer (score 0):

British English. The phrase "*We're just finishing dinner*" can mean either of your suggestions, but typically, it shows that the person is not yet ready to move on to some new activity. The meal might still be in progress but almost finished. Or the meal itself might have ended but conversation is still flowing.

The phrase can be spoken in two ways:

1. It may be a flat statement with a hint of an apology and a downward lilt at the end of the sentence. In this situation there is an implied temporary rejection of your interaction, "*I am not ready to speak or otherwise interact with you. Please try again later.*" In the UK the correct response would be to apologise (gently) for interrupting the person's dinner, and to ask when it might be a better time to try again.
2. Alternatively it may be an excited exclamation. You should still ask if you should try again in a few minutes, but the expectation is that the person is ready to interact with you now, or very shortly.

---

For the suggested alternatives,

- "*We have just finished dinner.*" means that meal time has recently ended, perhaps within the last five minutes or so. You might hear this if someone arrives late to a social occasion and has missed the meal itself.
- "*We will finish dinner very soon*" with the word *very* suggests that the food will be finished up within the next few minutes, but it does not necessarily and automatically mean that the meal time has ended: there might be drinks or conversation to follow. This is the kind of phrase I might expect a parent to say quietly to their young child who is impatient to move on to the next thing.

Comment: Conversely, it could also mean in a positive way "You won't have to wait very long, because we've nearly finished eating".

Comment: so what is the difference of meaning between "we are just  finishing  our  meal and we will finish our meal soon"

Comment: @user5577 - As I commented above, _We are just finishing our meal_ means literally that  the meal is at its last stage; we have eaten almost all the food.

Answer (score -1):

1. The action (having dinner) is finished.
2. The action (having dinner) will finish (didn't finish yet).