# So what is the difference of meaning between "we are just finishing our meal and we will finish our meal soon"?

Tags: meaning

So what is the difference of meaning between "we are just finishing our meal and we will finish our meal soon".

I think both of them mean the same. May be in the first one it is a special diner view as a process because you have invited many friends and are talking a lot  and in the second example it is a "normal" diner.

Comment: Maybe not quite a dupe, but to tag this from earlier today - https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/340212/whats-the-meaning-of-were-just-finishing-dinner

Comment: **In effect** they mean much the same and it has nothing to do with the number of diners. _We will finish our meal soon_ means what it says, _We are just finishing our meal_ is an idiomatic way of saying that the meal has reached its final stage, perhaps the last few spoonfuls of dessert!

Comment: If you're a quick eater, then at the time that you start eating, you may finish soon, but you're not just finishing because you only just started.

Answer (score 3):

They are not quite the same.

If a group of people at a table in a restaurant said "We are just finishing" I would expect them to be  about ready to put down their napkins and put on their coats. If they said "We will finish soon" they might be still be eating dessert.

Comment: In a restaurant, they don't want the staff to be nagging. "We are finishing soon" actually means "Go away & leave us alone!" :P

Comment: @DoneWithThis. Agreed that the staff would never say that. A rude customer waiting for a table where there's no m'aitre d might.